# Unix command to display/list distribution of numbers

Tags: unix, distribution

Is there a Unix command that I can run to visualize or state a distribution of numbers from a text file? Ideally I would like to use awk/cut and pipe it to this supposed command.

Comment: Actually, I would like to emphasize the visualization part. If it were a histogram bar, that would be really awesome.

Comment: Found it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949332/in-terminal-ascii-histograms-tool

Answer (score 1):

Would something as simple as `sort` and `uniq` help you?  For example, imagine `tmp` is a text file that looks like

```
1
1
3
4
1
9
```

Then the command

```
sort -n tmp | uniq -c
```

Would produce

```
3 1
1 3
1 4
1 9
```